Create a command for plotting multiple plots with the same definitions
I was trying to create a command to generate a line chart with multiple plots. The command should accept two arguments: the title and a list of plots. Each plot in the list should contain three elements: the color of the plot, the y-coordinates, and the legend. The x-coordinates should be the natural numbers.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
%\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\eloplot}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={#1},
    xlabel={Battles},
    ylabel={Elo},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=1000, ymax=1500,
    xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    ytick={1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\foreach \color/\data/\legend in {#2} {
    \addplot[color=\color, mark=square] coordinates {
        (0, 1000)
        \foreach \y [count=\i from 1] in \data {
            (\i,\y)
        }
    };
    \addlegendentry{\legend}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\eloplot{Elo of Various Heuristic Bots}{
    {blue, {1100, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500}, Bot 1},
    {red, {1050, 1100, 1175, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450}, Bot 2},
    {green, {1150, 1200, 1250, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1480, 1500}, Bot 3}
}

\end{document}

However, with this solution, Overleaf either reports an error or times out, even with a pro account.

Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! Would you mind completing your document with a \documentclass{} and a \end{document}? It would also be really helpful to answerers to see an example of your command in use, as is - even if it times out, as well as a picture showing something similar to what you'd like to achieve.

@Jasper ok, thank you! I don't know if other packages are needed to run this specific code, because it is a big document.

Do you still have the error message with your given MWE?

@Mensch if I remove the \eloplot call, everything compiles fine. But when I add it, it just keeps compiling forever until it times out. In a separate project with just that simple code snippet.

You need to prepare the list of coordinates in advance.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\diasaddplot}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l_tmpa_seq #2
  \use:e 
   {
    \exp_not:N \addplot[color=#1,mark=square]~coordinates~
     {
      (0,1000)
      \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \__dias_addplot_coords:nn
     };
    \exp_not:N\addlegendentry{\exp_not:V #3}
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__dias_addplot_coords:nn { (#1,#2) }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\eloplot}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title={#1},
    xlabel={Battles},
    ylabel={Elo},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=1000, ymax=1500,
    xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    ytick={1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
  ]
  \foreach \color/\data/\legend in {#2} {
    \diasaddplot{\color}{\data}{\legend}
  }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\eloplot{Elo of Various Heuristic Bots}{
    blue/{1100, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500}/Bot 1,
    red/{1050, 1100, 1175, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450}/Bot 2,
    green/{1150, 1200, 1250, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1480, 1500}/Bot 3
}

\end{document}

The \data is stored in a sequence that we can map with indices, so we can build the required pair.
Full expansion needs some control: we don't want to expand \addplot nor \addlegendentry and \legend only once (to protect possible accented characters).


Thank you, worked perfectly!

Very elegant code. // Just wondering about \NewDocumentCommand{\diasaddplot}{mmm}, which wants 3 mandatory arguments. A) However, if I delete one m it still works, when I change the legend-part in the input data. B) It doesn't use parameter #3 at all and still works. C) Deleting \exp_not:N\addlegendentry{\exp_not:V \legend} or replacing \legend by #3 works fine with changed Bot-legend entries. // What's the secret to all this behavior?

@MS-SPO The secret is that I should have written \exp_not:V #3

Right, but even as is … it seems to work. This is certainly by chance, perhaps related to scoping?

@MS-SPO No, it's just that #3 is \legend.

There's most likely a more pgfplotish solution to this, but the following works. I defined an expandable version that builds your list of coordinates using \ekvcsvloop of the expkv package (disclaimer: I wrote that package).
Additionally you need to expand the value of the legend entry, as \foreach creates a group and otherwise the value of your macros vanishes before its needed, for which pgfplots provides \addlegendentryexpanded.
Note also that if you use \foreach\x/\y in {<list>} you need to use / to separate the subitems in that list, not a nested comma separated list.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,expkv}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
%\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\countedCoordinates[1]
  {%
    \expanded
      {%
        \unexpanded{\@firstoftwo{\countedCoordinatesAux{1}}}%
        \ekvcsvloop\countedCoordinatesAux{#1}%
      }%
    \@gobble
  }
\newcommand\countedCoordinatesAux[3]
  {%
    (#1,#2)%
    \expandafter#3\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1}%
  }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\eloplot}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={#1},
  xlabel={Battles},
  ylabel={Elo},
  xmin=0, xmax=100,
  ymin=1000, ymax=1500,
  xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
  ytick={1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500},
  legend pos=north west,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
]
\foreach \color/\data/\legend in {#2} {
  \expanded{\noexpand\addplot[color=\color, mark=square] coordinates {
    (0, 1000)
    \expandafter\countedCoordinates\expandafter{\data}%
  }};
  \addlegendentryexpanded{\legend}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\eloplot{Elo of Various Heuristic Bots}{
    blue/{1100, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500}/Bot 1,
    red/{1050, 1100, 1175, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450}/Bot 2,
    green/{1150, 1200, 1250, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1480, 1500}/Bot 3
}

\end{document}



Nice. // For one out of many pgfplotish solutions kindly see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727504/245790

To add to the solutions variety here's one way to implement a pgfplotish approach, as @Skilmon thought about.
Step 1: data format
It's better, i.e. more universal, to stick to the format used e.g. in database systems: the table. By chance it's one of the data formats pgfplots can process,
So you may want to store or create your data as mybots.dat:
 t  Bot1 Bot2 Bot3
  0 1000 1000 1000
 10 1100 1050 1150
 20 1200 1100 1200
 30 1250 1175 1250
 40 1300 1250 1350
 50 1350 1300 1400
 60 1400 1350 1450
 70 1450 1400 1480
 80 1500 1450 1500

Step 2: don't stop adding plots
The key is to add as many plots per axis as your data allow:
...
    \addplot table [x=t, y=Bot1]{mybots.dat};
    \addplot table [x=t, y=Bot2]{mybots.dat};
    \addplot table [x=t, y=Bot3]{mybots.dat};
...

There are different ways to add the legend entries. I moved it into the axis' preamble, but you could use \addlegendentry as well after each \addplot. Depends on your preferences and needs.
Bonus / demo
I added just an other plot which evaluates Bot 1 vs. Bot 3, which is easy to do when data are in a table format ...

About using documentclass standalone
For me it's almost always better to separate the drawing from the textual content: this gives more flexibility and less unwanted interaction

use standalone for Tikz, pgfplots etc.
use e.g. article for your content
include compiled graphics via package graphicx

I described this several times, e.g. here.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
 % ~~~ pgfplotish solution ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Elo of Various Heuristic Bots},
        xlabel={Battles},
        ylabel={Elo},
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        ymin=1000, ymax=1500,
%       xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
%       ytick={1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500},
        legend pos=south east,              % <<<
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        legend entries={Bot 1, Bot 2, Bot3},% <<<
    ]
    \addplot table [x=t, y=Bot1]{mybots.dat};
    \addplot table [x=t, y=Bot2]{mybots.dat};
    \addplot table [x=t, y=Bot3]{mybots.dat};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

% ~~~ advantage of using a standard tabular format for data ~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        title=Correlation Bot 1 vs. 3,
   ]
    \addplot table [x=Bot1, y=Bot3]{mybots.dat};  
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

